# Handle multiple rows from SELECT in MSSQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm currently building a small system that can give our users rewards for doing different tasks for our partners. Doing X for partner Y will reward the user by Z amount. Instead of transferring a lot of small account movements all the time, we want to give a combined bonus for all the users activities for one day.

I want to build a Stored Procedure that can be run by the SQL Server Agent around midnight. This Stored Procedure will sum up the users earnings and add it to their account. However, I can only manage to get this working 1 user at the time. Is it possible to manage, lets say a 100, users earnings in 1 call to the Stored Procedure?

To break it down, I want a Stored Procedure that can handle 100 users total transactions in 1 call, instead of calling the Stored Procedure 100 times, 1 user at the time. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Here is some sample code I've been working on:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[rewards_dailybonus]
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @userid INT = 0
DECLARE @partnerId INT = 0
DECLARE @totalPoints INT = 0
DECLARE @theDate DATETIME = ''


    -- This SELECT should return 100 rows
    SELECT @userid = userid, @partnerId = partnerId, @totalPoints = SUM(points), @theDate = CAST(created AS DATE)
    FROM rewards_movements WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE
        transferred IS NULL
        AND
        CAST(created AS DATE) != CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
    GROUP BY userid, partnerId, CAST(created AS DATE)
    ORDER BY CAST(created AS DATE), userid ASC

    -- For each row from above SELECT, execute another Stored Procedure to add the points to a users account
    EXEC registerAccountMovement @userid, @totalPoints, 'Account movement notice'

    -- Set the points as transferred
    UPDATE rewards_movements SET transferred = GETDATE() WHERE userid = @userid AND partnerId = @partnerId
END
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried, sample data and schema, and desired results...

Comment: Yes it's possible. TVPs allow you to pass in a list of ids. Can't be much more helpful without table schemas etc.

Comment: how are you updating from the stored procedure. You can have the 100 users read from a table and do the computations for them in the Stored Procedure

Comment: I just added some of the sample code I've been working. Hope it makes sense!

Comment: Looks like your trying to use a `cursor`.  If you post what you're trying to accomplish in that cursor, we might be able to see if it's possible to do without.

Comment: Please show us the code that goes where you have the comment "*-- For each row from above SELECT accountmovements will be handled and added to the user*"  This needs to be changed to better interface with the rest of your procedure.

Comment: Just added some code for you, @RBarryYoung!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would think the code would look something like this:

```
with toupdate as (
      select userid, sum(earnings) as NewEarnings
      from tblEarnings e
      where e.earningdate = cast(getdate() -1 as date)
      group by userid
     )
update users
    set earnings = earnings + newearnings
    from toupdate
    where users.userid = toupdate.userid
```

This is obviously just a sketch, but it shows how do what you want in a set oriented fashion.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I cooked up a solution close to this that works :-)